# How to use iText java PDF library with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, itext, application-server

Google search results suggested that it's possible via [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/index.php) . This bridge requires Java Application Server. My host (bluehost) does not allow to run any Java Application Server. What are the alternatives in this case to make iText work? Switching a host is not viable option for me.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are on shared hosting that doesn't run Java, I don't think this can be done at all.

Comment: If java is not installed, there is not much you can do. Your best bet is probably a PHP based PDF library, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.freepdf

Comment: Hey, if you're generating PDFs, I can fairly strongly recommend [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) which uses the super-awesome webkit rendering engine to render html documents to pdf. It has few external dependencies, so it's pretty easy to get going. It's what [pdfmyurl](http://pdfmyurl.com/) uses, so you can try that out if you want to test your results.

Comment: A related question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648715/best-pdf-generator-in-php-mpdf-or-fpdf

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for those still looking for an answer, may I suggest having Java do your work for you as a REST service using Jersey (JAX-RS), then just call the service from PHP. You can put your Java service on a host that does allow Java and you can call that service from PHP using cURL (or even file_get_contents *if* your host allows it and *if* you know what you're doing).

Loose coupling over RESTful services is allows you to have your Java service and your PHP app on separate hosts. Don't waste you time with a PHP/Java Bridge. It's perfectly sane to call a RESTful service with a Java back-end from PHP. This way, later if you decide, your would rather re-do the service in C# or something else, at least there will be 0 impact on the PHP app because you used a language neutral RESTful approach.

I have not had any performance issues using this approach myself, YMMV

(It's mostly a matter of design: It's usually better to "bolt" things together then "weld" them together.)

Also, Java with JAX-RS is very very simple (IMHO, but again .. YMMV)

Answer (score 0):

There's always [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), a C# translation of iText.  Will your host let you run C#?

It looks like you can call C# from PHP, as [detailed here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Using-the-.NET-Assembly-in-PHP/).

Comment: Just my opinion, but if Java is not allowed, I think its highly unlikely that there is a .NET Framework environment where C# apps run. And the COM interface of PHP is not really something you want to use. By the way, the article is from 2002.

Comment: 2002?  Eek!  Well I doubt it's _harder_ to connect the two now.

Comment: Just checked, C# is not an option either. I guess, I've to look for other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The ITEXT website specifically says JAVA and .NET, Wish they can also build the PHP or PERL version

I have used the Java Itext, Its superb!!

Answer (score -1):

[PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/) is a command line tool installed on many Linux systems. It is a front end to the iText library. It may do what you need. You'd have to shell out to the command line to invoke it from PHP.

Comment: Pdftk is a front end to a very, very, very old version of iText.