# How can I use Itext in PHP?

Tags: php, yii2, itext, preg-replace, show-hide

[Itext](https://itextpdf.com/en) is a powerful toolkit for *PDF generation*, *PDF programming*, *handling & manipulation*. **Java** sample:

```
public void processPDF(String src, String dest) {

try {

  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
  PdfArray refs = null;
  PRIndirectReference reference = null;

  int nPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();

  for (int i = 1; i <= nPages; i++) {
    PdfDictionary dict = reader.getPageN(i);
    PdfObject object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    if (object.isArray()) {
      refs = dict.getAsArray(PdfName.CONTENTS);
      ArrayList<PdfObject> references = refs.getArrayList();

      for (PdfObject r : references) {

        reference = (PRIndirectReference) r;
        PRStream stream = (PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject(reference);
        byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
        String dd = new String(data, "UTF-8");

        dd = dd.replaceAll("@pattern_1234", "trueValue");
        dd = dd.replaceAll("test", "tested");

        stream.setData(dd.getBytes());
      }

    }
    if (object instanceof PRStream) {
      PRStream stream = (PRStream) object;

      byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
      String dd = new String(data, "UTF-8");
      System.out.println("content---->" + dd);
      dd = dd.replaceAll("@pattern_1234", "trueValue");
      dd = dd.replaceAll("This", "FIRST");

      stream.setData(dd.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
  }
  PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
  stamper.close();
  reader.close();
}

catch (Exception e) {
}
```

}

The question is how I can use this ***toolkit for PHP*** or there is *any **PHP toolkit** like this*?
I am using **Yii2 Framework** and just want to *replace text inside* a certain file (**.doc, .docx, .pdf**)

Original file:
[image: Original file]
Expected file after editing:
[image: Expected file after editing]

Comment: You can use the mPDF lib for this in PHP: https://mpdf.github.io/
This lib provide a method `OverWrite()` with which you can replace text in PDF files.

Comment: I've tried, It did create a new file, however, the content remains the old one :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use iText java PDF library with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390675/how-to-use-itext-java-pdf-library-with-php)

Comment: yeah, I've already read that one! My question is more specific, by the way.

Comment: A word of warning: The iText code in your question is an example that **won't work for generic PDFs**. It only "works" for very simple PDFs and only for search and replacement text with characters as used in Western European languages. Furthermore, your explicit and implicit use of `UTF-8` here most likely damages more than necessary as PDF content streams are not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @mkl In fact, I only use it to replace phone numbers and emails which are used with Latin strings so it's really ok for this project. I've tried Itext with Java, and it runs perfectly. The problem now is to search text from pdf and replace or hide it. :P