# PDF generation in PHP or JavaScript (possible ?) or in another way

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I have a html page which contains a `<div></div>` section.
There is a link, I would like when someone click on the Link to generate a PDF which contains exactly the div section content.

How can I handle that in PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best pdf generator in PHP , mpdf or fpdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648715/best-pdf-generator-in-php-mpdf-or-fpdf)

Answer (score 1):

check the php pdf functions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php)

Comment: +1, but note that it relies on a third-party library, which requires a commercial licence to use all its features. (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdf.requirements.php for more details)

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, but [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) seems to be quite good.

Its a PHP class for generating PDF documents.

Good ratings on the web, and it looks like it's under active development as well. Worth having a look at.