# PHP PDF Generator Advice

Tags: php, pdf

Can anybody advise on the best PDF generator class/library to use with PHP? Preferably one which is maintained.

I am aware that this is a duplicate of the following question, however, the accepted answer is over 3 years old and I want to know whether the answer has changed since this time.

[Which one is the best PDF-API for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648715/best-pdf-generator-in-php-mpdf-or-fpdf)

Thank you

Comment: [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) is by far the _easiest_ I've tried, but maybe not the most flexible. Depends what you're trying to do..

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but this class seems somewhat underdeveloped at the moment. I think I will stick with the tcpdf class :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try TCPDF, have good features
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Also simple HTML to PDF Converter API in (PHP, C#, ASP.net C#, ASP VB.net, JAVA,...)

from "PDF CROWD"
http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/

very simple to use, but I think this API may need to purchase even they provide a free test account..

Comment: Thank you very much, I am currently looking at the tcpdf one. Do you know whether it does HTML to PDF?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply... see the examples "6" in tcpdf.org [http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.pdf], It support HTML, If you use html file - I think you have to read the file to one variable [$html_file_content = fopen('myfile.html', 'r');] and then convert to PDF.

Comment: Thank you very much, did see that but wanted to make sure it worked well as they cannot always be trusted :-)

Comment: There is problem with image reading. You have to specify the absolute path not relative.

Comment: I always specify absolute not relative anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://www.PDFnow.com?

Provides a powerful template engine, and is pretty easy to use.

Supports complex layouts, layouts for multiple pages, invoices spreading separate pages, pagenumbers, headers, footers, etc. Definitively much better than fpdf.

You can simply integrate it into your PHP code by:

```
generatePdf(<templateName>, <ParameterArray>);
```

very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ Convert HTML to PDF using WebKit engine.
It can be used from PHP easily. For example, there is a bundle for Symfony2: http://knpbundles.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle

Answer (score 0):

Best One is **TCPDF**

http://www.tcpdf.org/

Never Use **DOMPDF**

Comment: @chhameed for customization TCPDF is the best one. Besides the the there is a very good documentation available for the TCPDF but not for the DOMPDF