# How can I export a web form to a PDF with Javascript or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, pdf

If I missed a similar question, I'm truly sorry - I have done what I believe to be quite a bit of digging on this subject and come up empty handed.

Is it possible (or practical) to do one of the following:

**1)** Use the data from a web form to populate fields in a PDF?

or **2)** Simply upload the PDF and allow the user to complete and submit it online?

I don't necessarily have a preference between the two, other than the most practical solution.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript ? explains xml to pdf using javascript only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mPDF is a PHP class which generates PDF files from UTF-8 encoded HTML. It is based on FPDF and HTML2FPDF, with a number of enhancements.

check it out [MPDF1](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/)

Comment: I think this may be the ticket - I'll let you know if this works, but I'm going to go ahead and mark this as answered. Thanks!

Comment: This has [already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648715/best-pdf-generator-in-php-mpdf-or-fpdf) on StackOverflow.