# Print web page with original look

Tags: printing, cross-browser, media-queries, html

I want to achieve print functionality such that user can print out the web form and use it as paper form for the same purpose. Of course I do not need all the web page header and footer to be printed, just content of a div which take most of the page. I did play around with media print css and menage print result to look almost as original page. But the I tried to print it in another browser(Chrome) and it is all messed. (before I tried Mozilla).

For the web form I user css framework Twitter Bootstrap and I had to override its css (in print media) for almost each element individually to get some normal look in the print result.

My question is is there some way (framework/plugin) to print just what you see on the page, maybe as an image or something?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with PHP you can try the PHP class files of [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) or those of [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/).

Or there is also [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) which renders HTML to PDF, but this will include more than just the information of one div.

And for further info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648715/best-pdf-generator-in-php-mpdf-or-fpdf) is a post on Stack where users are discussing which they think is best.