# Removing cell border without CSS

Tags: html, pdf

I have created a HTML table, in which, I have hidden some horizontal borders using CSS.

The same table, *when converted to pdf*, doesn't hide the borders **as CSS doesn't work with PDF**. Is there any way to format the table, without CSS, so that it can be properly formatted in the PDF conversion.

Comment: Did you tried html `border="0"` ?

Comment: That will remove borders of the complete table and I want to remove only for td and that too only horizontal.

Comment: Have you tried using a different piece of software when converting to PDF, I've never had an issue with PDF conversion lacking CSS.

Comment: I am converting it through php and fpdf.

Comment: what about including css inside html `<style>` tags? if it's already like that, then search for other class that take in consideration css when converting to pdf!

Comment: Maybe this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648715/best-pdf-generator-in-php-mpdf-or-fpdf

Comment: You need to use inline styling i.e. `<td style="...">`

Comment: style tag and inline styling is not working

Answer (score 1):

```
<table frame="box" >
  <tr>
     <td>First</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Just use frame="box" and you will only have border outside the table.
Hope it works!