# best plugin to generate pdf from php

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I know this might be down voted and get closed. But i am looking for free plugin to generate pdf files from php.

I have checked [Which one is the best PDF-API for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648715/which-is-th-best-pdf-generator-for-php) this question but its almost 6 years old.

I think there might be many new plugin will build till the time.

Does anyone advise on this?

Before this question get closed.

Comment: _"Before this question get closed."_ I sincerely hope that you never get a answer to any of your questions with a attitude like that.

Comment: Its not about attitude. you can see close(2)

Comment: I will not closed this question but might other user/moderator will do. As off topic or too broad.

Comment: You can see the best examples here. http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Comment: Thanks Vijay. i will check that.

Comment: [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure which one that fits your requirements.
But I seen much people talking good about tcpdf
See the list below of a couple:

- ApacheFOP
- dompdf
- FPDF
- html2ps
- mPDF
- PDFlib
- TCPDF
- wkhtmltopdf
- Zend_Pdf

source:
[Which one is the best PDF-API for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648715/which-is-th-best-pdf-generator-for-php)

Comment: Please, do not answer questions like these. It's off-topic and only lowers the quality of SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using native `PHP` go with `TCPDF` library.
http://www.tcpdf.org/

Comment: Don't answer questions which are opinion based.

Comment: @Daan What about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648715/which-is-th-best-pdf-generator-for-php?

Comment: @404 The question got closed, what's your point ?

Comment: My point is there are many answers to that question.

Comment: @404 Two wrongs doesn't make a right

Comment: Apologies to all of you. My intention was to get the plugin name.  I don't want to make anyone angry.