# I have an image and I want to edit that image (place text etc) and convert that image to PDF. Is there an easy way to do it PHP?

Tags: php, image, laravel, pdf

The image is of fixed size and I want to update that image for every user like updating the username and date etc. Then I want to convert that image to PDF with the A4 printing size. How can this be achieved in PHP/Laravel.

Comment: See my answer below. It would allow you to create it in html and convert to PDF like you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by first creating a responsive html and then converting that html to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

There are various libraries available for pdf generation for PHP.

e.g. there is MPDF which allows you to create a html and pass it to the library and it converts it into pdf.

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

You can also check a comparison of various other generators here: [Which one is the best PDF-API for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648715/which-one-is-the-best-pdf-api-for-php)

Comment: Thanks Nabeel but I know about the libraries. The main challenge here is to edit the image and I think there are libraries available for that too. The other thing I am thinking of creating a responsive html and then convert to PDF.

Comment: to add text to image (without removing anything) you can use that image as a background and add the text as html on it

Comment: if this ans helped, please vote up and select as best :)

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the `php_GD` library and in particular, the [`imagettftext`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php). For image to PDF conversions, try using `ImageMagick`

Answer (score 0):

You can add text to an image with Intervention using [`text()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/text) method:

```
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 120, 100);
```

Then, you could just create simple HTML wrap for an image to convert it to PDF with [any appropriate tool](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) or [package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf):

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('view.with.image', $data);
return $pdf->download('image.pdf');
```

Or, you could convert image to PDF using ImageMagick (CLI example):

```
convert image.jpg image.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely take a look at using [Snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) by barryvdh

One you have the package pulled in through composer. It's as simple as using the wrapper the package provides.

```
    $snappy = \App::make('snappy.pdf');

     $snappy->generateFromHtml("Link to your image here", '/tmp/NameofYourPDF.pdf');
```

This example is here is then saving it to the `/tmp` folder on the server.

Have used this in the past and it makes it very straight forward to use.

You need to have wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltoimage installed. You can download wkhtmltopdf from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html